# UIButton click event not working inside UIStackView Swift4

Tags: swift4

I have add three UIButton inside UIStackView but UIButton click event not working for Swift 4. How to fix it?

Comment: Please try (1) Have you connected button click event of your button to your view ? eg. connecting touch up inside event or creating referencing outlet and then addtarget (2) try adding a 'view' in stackview and then add button inside the added view.

Comment: There is no connection between UIStackView and UIButton Action, please check code again in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your buttons again by following these steps:

1- Create your buttons and set a fixed height and height.
2 - Select all and throw into the stack. 
3- Create a button action reference in the class and do whatever you want.

Obs: The only view that will exist in your storyboars will be the one that comes by default.